# Зачем нужна серверная часть AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Я начал изучение AngularJS недавно. Но подумал что было бы не крайне круто если хостить сайт на нем будет сложно и потому эту проблему стоит обдумать заранее.

Как я узнал из англоязычного ресурса [NodeJS не обязателен](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947084/how-to-host-an-angularjs-app-in-domain) для запуска своего приложения, так как все действия могут быть обработаны локально клиентом.

Какой тогда смысл в AngularJS? От части упростить работу? В плане обрабатывать данные на сервере будет какой-нибудь PHP, верно? Тогда AngularJS просто упрощает работу с элементами на странице.

И последнее: можно ли просто подключить TS скрипт к страничке что бы выполнить его? То есть программу не нужно переписывать под "клиентский" вариант. То есть еще раз, и серверный и клиентский варианты выглядят одинаково?

Comment: Ангуляр существенно развязывает руки для разработки на стороне клиента, что позволяет строить более отзывчивые приложения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AngularJS - это клиентский фреймворк. (Кстати, если вы упомянули TypeScript - наверное, вы имели в виду Angular, а не AngularJS. Но ответ от этого не меняется). Будучи клиентским фреймворком, он не нуждается в сервере (но сервер вам все равно может понадобиться для серверной части вашего приложения) и у него нет никакого "серверного" варианта.

Node.js вам понадобится для следующих вещей:

1. Компиляция (также называемая транспиляцией) скриптов. К примеру, вы упомянули TypeScript. Браузеры не могут выполнять TypeScript, перед использованием этих скриптов их надо компилировать при помощи программы tsc (TypeScript Compiler). Для запуска tcs вам понадобится node.js, потому что tcs - это просто скрипт.
2. Сборка ресурсов. Без этого шага можно обойтись, но обычно рекомендуется все используемые ресурсы упаковать в несколько файлов ("бандлов") для более быстрой загрузки браузером. Для этой цели придумано много инструментов - но обычно они тоже запускаются при помощи node.js

После компиляции и сборки у вас будет набор статических файлов - и вот эти файлы вы можете загрузить на любой хостинг. **Вам не требуется node.js на хостинге - но вам потребуется node.js на вашем компьютере.**

Серверная же часть для вашего приложения, скорее всего, будет выполнять следующее:

3. Там будут лежать ваши клиентские скрипты
4. Она будет работать с БД и отвечать клиенту на AJAX-запросы

Для пункта 3 подойдет любой веб-сервер, это базовая функциональность веб=серверов. Для пункта 4 подойдет любой серверный язык - PHP, C#, Ruby...

Можно и вовсе отказаться от серверной части, если логика вашего приложения позволяет обойтись без нее. Например, если вы делаете расширение для браузера.

Comment: Вы сломали мой мозг только что. То есть мы компилируем TypeScript и получаем набор JS скриптов только 1 раз? Я думал это происходит так быстро что принято компилировать скрипт сервером постоянно. Только 1 вопрос еще: клиент может компилировать TypeScript сам? Спасибо вам за отличный ответ!

Comment: @Telion в теории - может, но библиотек для такого не написано.